# How to track total number of open files / file descriptors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-descriptor

I have a code that iterates over a bunch of registers. It opens a few file descriptors with the only purpose of silencing (anoying) messages triggered by external libraries. The file descriptors are opened by:

```
import sys
import os
...
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    oldstderr_fno = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
    os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)
    # here I call the noisy external library
    os.dup2(oldstderr_fno, 2)
    del oldstderr_fno
```

The code runs fine if the number of iterations is small. When I try to iterate through the whole dataset, I end up getting the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I suspect the error comes from the way I am silencing the external library calls.

I tried to track where I am failing to close the file descriptors by following the outputs of:

```
import psutil
open_fd = len(psutil.Process().open_files())
print("Open FDs: %d" % open_fd)
```

However the number of reported open files is constant (only 2, as expected from other parts of the code).

Questions (any answer for any is very welcomed):

1. Any other cleaner way to silence noisy external libraries?
2. Am I leaving some file descriptor open? It should be closed by the ***with*** clause, right?
3. Any other suggestion on how to track leaking file descriptors in Python?

Comment: File descriptors are just `int`s and `del oldstderr_fno` won't close the file, you have to `os.close()` it.  Not sure why `open_files()` doesn't list it.

Comment: Nice suggestion with `os.close`. It solved the issue! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Following the valuable comment provided by **Tavian Barnes**, I got to a solution by closing the file descriptor explicitly so that the first block of code became:

```
import sys
import os
...
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    oldstderr_fno = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
    os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)
    # here I call the noisy external library
    os.dup2(oldstderr_fno, 2)
    os.close(oldstderr_fno)                # <-- new line that really closes the fd
    del oldstderr_fno
```